# pandas read_html not finding soup table

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I am using bs4 to extract this table:

```
tx_tableST = soup4.find("table", attrs={"class": "t18Standard"})
```

tx_tableST:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="t18Standard" summary="">
<tbody><tr><th align="left" class="t18ReportHeader" id="DATE_CREATED">Date</th><th align="center" class="t18ReportHeader" id="TRANSACTION_REFERENCE">Ref</th><th align="right" class="t18ReportHeader" id="TRANSACTION_TYPE">Trans Type</th><th align="center" class="t18ReportHeader" id="TRANSACTION_DESCRIPTION">Description</th><th align="right" class="t18ReportHeader" id="TRANSACTION_AMOUNT">Amount</th><th align="left" class="t18ReportHeader" id="AMOUNT_DEBIT_CREDIT_INDICATOR">D/C</th><th align="right" class="t18ReportHeader" id="AMOUNT_TRANSACTION_FEE">Fee</th><th align="right" class="t18ReportHeader" id="BALANCE">Balance</th><th align="left" class="t18ReportHeader" id="DESTINATION_MSISDN">MSISDN From</th><th align="center" class="t18ReportHeader" id="MSISDN">MSISDN To</th><th align="center" class="t18ReportHeader" id="USER_REFERENCE">User Reference</th><th align="center" class="t18ReportHeader" id="DRIVER_REFERENCE">Driver Reference</th></>
<tr class="highlight-row"><td class="t18data" headers="Date">01-MAY-2020</td><td class="t18data" headers="Ref">4697050505</td><td align="right" class="t18data" headers="Trans Type">ADJUSTMENT</td><td class="t18data" headers="Description">ACCOUNT ADJUSTMENT (4696753848)</td><td align="right" class="t18data" headers="Amount">R 0.00</td><td class="t18data" headers="D/C">C</td><td align="right" class="t18data" headers="Fee">R 0.00</td><td align="right" class="t18data" headers="Balance">R 0.00</td><td class="t18data" headers="MSISDN From">27110036978</td><td class="t18data" headers="MSISDN To">27110036978</td><td class="t18data" headers="User Reference"> - </td><td class="t18data" headers="Driver Reference"> - </td></tr>
<tr class="highlight-row"><td class="t18data" headers="Date">01-MAY-2020</td><td class="t18data" headers="Ref">4697997721</td><td align="right" class="t18data" headers="Trans Type">PAYMENT</td><td class="t18data" headers="Description">PAYMENT FROM NOKUFIKA MDLIVA</td><td align="right" class="t18data" headers="Amount">R 150.00</td><td class="t18data" headers="D/C">C</td><td align="right" class="t18data" headers="Fee">R 0.00</td><td align="right" class="t18data" headers="Balance">R 150.00</td><td class="t18data" headers="MSISDN From">27837331123</td><td class="t18data" headers="MSISDN To">27110036978</td><td class="t18data" headers="User Reference">20081</td><td class="t18data" headers="Driver Reference">0000</td></tr>
<tr class="highlight-row"><td class="t18data" headers="Date">01-MAY-2020</td><td class="t18data" headers="Ref">4699988658</td><td align="right" class="t18data" headers="Trans Type">PAYMENT</td><td class="t18data" headers="Description">PAYMENT FROM NOMALADY NGQONDI</td><td align="right" class="t18data" headers="Amount">R 150.00</td><td class="t18data" headers="D/C">C</td><td align="right" class="t18data" headers="Fee">R 0.00</td><td align="right" class="t18data" headers="Balance">R 300.00</td><td class="t18data" headers="MSISDN From">27607607003</td><td class="t18data" headers="MSISDN To">27110036978</td><td class="t18data" headers="User Reference">20104</td><td class="t18data" headers="Driver Reference">0000</td></tr>
<tr class="highlight-row"><td class="t18data" headers="Date">01-MAY-2020</td><td class="t18data" headers="Ref">4700300759</td><td align="right" class="t18data" headers="Trans Type">PAYMENT</td><td class="t18data" headers="Description">PAYMENT FROM KHUNJULWA ZWENI</td><td align="right" class="t18data" headers="Amount">R 250.00</td><td class="t18data" headers="D/C">C</td><td align="right" class="t18data" headers="Fee">R 0.00</td><td align="right" class="t18data" headers="Balance">R 550.00</td><td class="t18data" headers="MSISDN From">27792465091</td><td class="t18data" headers="MSISDN To">27110036978</td><td class="t18data" headers="User Reference">20088</td><td class="t18data" headers="Driver Reference">20088</td></tr>
<tr class="highlight-row"><td class="t18data" headers="Date">01-MAY-2020</td><td class="t18data" headers="Ref">4700302458</td><td align="right" class="t18data" headers="Trans Type">PAYMENT</td><td class="t18data" headers="Description">PAYMENT FROM KHUNJULWA ZWENI</td><td align="right" class="t18data" headers="Amount">R 150.00</td><td class="t18data" headers="D/C">C</td><td align="right" class="t18data" headers="Fee">R 0.00</td><td align="right" class="t18data" headers="Balance">R 700.00</td><td class="t18data" headers="MSISDN From">27792465091</td><td class="t18data" headers="MSISDN To">27110036978</td><td class="t18data" headers="User Reference">20084</td><td class="t18data" headers="Driver Reference">20084</td></tr>
<tr class="highlight-row"><td class="t18data" headers="Date">01-MAY-2020</td><td class="t18data" headers="Ref">4700355484</td><td align="right" class="t18data" headers="Trans Type">BANK PURSE UNLOAD</td><td class="t18data" headers="Description">CASHED OUT TO LINKED BANK ACCOUNT</td><td align="right" class="t18data" headers="Amount">R 700.00</td><td class="t18data" headers="D/C">D</td><td align="right" class="t18data" headers="Fee">R 24.15</td><td align="right" class="t18data" headers="Balance">R 0.00</td><td class="t18data" headers="MSISDN From">27110036978</td><td class="t18data" headers="MSISDN To">27110036978</td><td class="t18data" headers="User Reference"> - </td><td class="t18data" headers="Driver Reference"> - </td></tr>
<tr class="highlight-row"><td class="t18data" headers="Date">02-MAY-2020</td><td class="t18data" headers="Ref">4701106254</td><td align="right" class="t18data" headers="Trans Type">PAYMENT</td><td class="t18data" headers="Description">PAYMENT FROM AMAHLE MTALANA</td><td align="right" class="t18data" headers="Amount">R 150.00</td><td class="t18data" headers="D/C">C</td><td align="right" class="t18data" headers="Fee">R 0.00</td><td align="right" class="t18data" headers="Balance">R 150.00</td><td class="t18data" headers="MSISDN From">27783245654</td><td class="t18data" headers="MSISDN To">27110036978</td><td class="t18data" headers="User Reference">20102</td><td class="t18data" headers="Driver Reference">20102</td></tr>
<tr class="highlight-row"><td class="t18data" headers="Date">02-MAY-2020</td><td class="t18data" headers="Ref">4701696857</td><td align="right" class="t18data" headers="Trans Type">PAYMENT</td><td class="t18data" headers="Description">PAYMENT FROM AMAHLE MTALANA</td><td align="right" class="t18data" headers="Amount">R 300.00</td><td class="t18data" headers="D/C">C</td><td align="right" class="t18data" headers="Fee">R 0.00</td><td align="right" class="t18data" headers="Balance">R 450.00</td><td class="t18data" headers="MSISDN From">27783245654</td><td class="t18data" headers="MSISDN To">27110036978</td><td class="t18data" headers="User Reference">20113</td><td class="t18data" headers="Driver Reference">20113</td></tr>
<tr class="highlight-row"><td class="t18data" headers="Date">02-MAY-2020</td><td class="t18data" headers="Ref">4702064068</td><td align="right" class="t18data" headers="Trans Type">PAYMENT</td><td class="t18data" headers="Description">PAYMENT FROM ASEMAHLE KHIBITHWAYO</td><td align="right" class="t18data" headers="Amount">R 150.00</td><td class="t18data" headers="D/C">C</td><td align="right" class="t18data" headers="Fee">R 0.00</td><td align="right" class="t18data" headers="Balance">R 600.00</td><td class="t18data" headers="MSISDN From">27798230085</td><td class="t18data" headers="MSISDN To">27110036978</td><td class="t18data" headers="User Reference">0798230085</td><td class="t18data" headers="Driver Reference">20094</td></tr>
<tr class="highlight-row"><td class="t18data" headers="Date">02-MAY-2020</td><td class="t18data" headers="Ref">4702475906</td><td align="right" class="t18data" headers="Trans Type">PAYMENT</td><td class="t18data" headers="Description">PAYMENT FROM NOKUPUMELELA SOGCWAYI</td><td align="right" class="t18data" headers="Amount">R 150.00</td><td class="t18data" headers="D/C">C</td><td align="right" class="t18data" headers="Fee">R 0.00</td><td align="right" class="t18data" headers="Balance">R 750.00</td><td class="t18data" headers="MSISDN From">27717913433</td><td class="t18data" headers="MSISDN To">27110036978</td><td class="t18data" headers="User Reference">20091</td><td class="t18data" headers="Driver Reference">optional</td></tr>
<tr class="highlight-row"><td class="t18data" headers="Date">02-MAY-2020</td><td class="t18data" headers="Ref">4703712930</td><td align="right" class="t18data" headers="Trans Type">BANK PURSE UNLOAD</td><td class="t18data" headers="Description">CASHED OUT TO LINKED BANK ACCOUNT</td><td align="right" class="t18data" headers="Amount">R 750.00</td><td class="t18data" headers="D/C">D</td><td align="right" class="t18data" headers="Fee">R 25.88</td><td align="right" class="t18data" headers="Balance">R 0.00</td><td class="t18data" headers="MSISDN From">27110036978</td><td class="t18data" headers="MSISDN To">27110036978</td><td class="t18data" headers="User Reference"> - </td><td class="t18data" headers="Driver Reference"> - </td></tr>
<tr class="highlight-row"><td class="t18data" headers="Date">03-MAY-2020</td><td class="t18data" headers="Ref">4705376158</td><td align="right" class="t18data" headers="Trans Type">PAYMENT</td><td class="t18data" headers="Description">PAYMENT FROM ASIPHE ANDRIES ANDRIES</td><td align="right" class="t18data" headers="Amount">R 150.00</td><td class="t18data" headers="D/C">C</td><td align="right" class="t18data" headers="Fee">R -</td><td align="right" class="t18data" headers="Balance">R 150.00</td><td class="t18data" headers="MSISDN From">27717331109</td><td class="t18data" headers="MSISDN To">27110036978</td><td class="t18data" headers="User Reference">20083</td><td class="t18data" headers="Driver Reference">0000</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

However, when using pandas to read the table, it doesn't seem to pick it up.
I've tried:

```
table = pd.read_html(str(tx_tableST), flavor='bs4')[0]
table = pd.read_html(str(tx_tableST))[0]
table = pd.read_html(tx_tableST)[0]
```

Is there any reason why it shouldn't read the table?

Comment: The tables may be populated by Javascript. We can take a look if you provide the URL.

Comment: ^^ please provide url when possible